# Display employees in frontend end magento

Tags: php, magento, tabs, grid

I have created an admin grid and tab for adding new employees in my project. How can I display these employees (inserted in database) in the front end of my website on clicking a link, say **List All**. That link is in my home page.

```
<li class="level0 nav-3 level-top parent">
            <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() ?>employee/index/list" class="nav_left">
                <span class="nav_right">
                    <span class="nav_inner_container">List All</span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
```

This will be the link. The url may be project.com/employee/index/list.

Did i have to create any **phtml** file for that?

I am very new to Magento. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: If you add a ListController in your employee module, then you could change your url structure to project.com/employee/list

Comment: Thank you for guiding me. I added that. now what will be in that listController?

Comment: Add the code from indexController/list (method) to ListController/index (method).. You may also me to change some layout xml for employee.xml

Comment: if you find my answer helpful the accept my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
you can find many way to do this
```

this is simple way i think using query

```
 $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');   
    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM employee_master ';
    $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
    print_r($results);
```

here in `$results` you can find all details just format your result in to your way.here `employee_master` is sample table name `write your table name`

Answer (score 0):

use Magento models and collection.
Maybe this link will help you figure it out:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics